# How to use HTC opensenseSDK?

Tags: android

I downloaded and test HTC opensense SDK . But I can't test any sample application . The main.xml file in the layout show like this

The following classes could not be found:

> - com.htc.painting.engine.HTCPaintingView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML,
>     Create Class)
> - com.htc.painting.penmenu.PenMenu (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create
>     Class)

How can I solve this problem ?

I see log cat error like this

```
10-04 12:02:05.001: ERROR/dalvikvm(580): Could not find class 'com.htc.painting.penmenu.PenMenu', referenced from method com.htc.demo.penmenu.MainActivity.init
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.htc.demo.penmenu/com.htc.demo.penmenu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class com.htc.painting.engine.HtcPaintingView
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class com.htc.painting.engine.HtcPaintingView
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at com.htc.demo.penmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     ... 11 more
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.htc.painting.engine.HtcPaintingView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.htc.demo.penmenu-1.apk]
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:542)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
10-04 12:02:05.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: did you add the HTCExtension.jar to your project build path in eclipse

Comment: Yes , I run the sample project of HTC opensense API . So , in this project HTCExtension.jar already add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speak with a person from HTC,in samples only one example is working  there will be update in few weeks and whole functions will be supported other

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to install HTC SKD properly as written on [this page](http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/download-instructions).
2. When opening project from sample, make sure to check Build Target to HTC Tablet Extension

This problem is that main.xml references custom View, which is in this case in HTCExtension.jar archive, so you must have HTCExtension.jar on build path.

But I didn't have any problem opening sample project, everything was set up correctly and could be built.
Try to reinstall whole SDK and open sample again.

Comment: Yes , I have made your opinion . But when I run example the applicaiton force close.