# Pen input in Android tablet

Tags: android

I want to use pen in android tablet . I use pen and want to write text with pen. How can I develop the android application to be accept only pen input in EditText . Can I use pen in emulator ? Is there any usable API for this .?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only HTC supports a pen on some their android tablets (please someone correct me if I'm wrong, I may not be up-to-date on these things). Their pen can be used concurrently while you're touching the device because their screen can tell the difference between your finger and their special pen.

Here is a link to their pen api

http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/tablet-pen

(free registration with their site is required I believe)

I believe they have an HTC SDK you can download with the AVD manager, but I just don't know if it comes with a special emulator for their pen api -- I haven't tried it yet.

Also other android tablets/phones can be used with pens, even if they're technically not made to support pens (but those pens are just special styluses that emulate the capacitive touch of your finger), so with those devices, the screen can not tell the difference between your fingers and that pen (so you can not assign them different functions which is definitely not as good).

Comment: So, I test htc opensense sdk for tablet-pen but I can't test their sample . See in my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594377/how-to-use-htc-opensensesdk

Comment: Actually, as labeled only one out of their four samples works on the emulator itself. I just tried it myself and that pen api code sample worked for me. You'll just have to use the mouse to emulate your finger, then you use the mouse while pressing the letter P (to emulate the Pen). If the mouse is locked in Pen-mode, you press Q to get out of it. Plus, if you want to use the two buttons on your HTC pen, you can add some code to the switch statements in question, and just press 1 or 2 while you're clicking on the mouse (if I remember correctly).